# Right mouse button not working (Ubuntu 22.04)?

Tags: mouse, ubuntu-22.04

I have Ubuntu 22.04 with all latest updates. Starting today (01.06.2022) my right mouse button is not working, so, for instance, when clicking on a file icon in the file viewer, before clicking on the right button would show a menu with options for "move to trash" etc. Now it only does the same as clicking the left button!

My mouse is an Ultra Technology Gaming mouse, model: 29UTX-00X10, if that matters. (Connected with usb, if that matters)
No problems with that until now!

Any ideas? How can I go about investigating this?

Comment: Migrated at the request of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in 22.04 resulting in right mouseclicks being ignored when they are unhurried (slow) .

Almost every desktop registers the right mouse click when letting go of the button. In ubuntu 22.04 its registered when pressing the right mouse and then there is a time limit when you can let go of the button. Most people do this slower then implemented, resulting in a not working right mouse button.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng/+bug/1987157?comments=all

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, upgrading to Ubuntu 22.10 solved this issue for me.